# PromQL expression to find common labels in two intervals

Tags: expression, prometheus, alert, promql

Lets say i have the following metrics collected from now-60m to now-30m -

```
fruits{name="apple"} 1
fruits{name="orange"} 1
fruits{name="pear"} 1
```

and the following metrics collected from now-30m to now

```
fruits{name="banana"} 1
fruits{name="pear"} 1
fruits{name="watermelon"} 1
```

How would i go about writing an alert rule to check if any fruit is present in both collections and it's name? In this case it will be

```
pear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
count(last_over_time(fruits[30m] offset 30m)) by (name)
and
count(last_over_time(fruits[30m])) by (name)
```

It should return `name` labels, which existed on both time ranges - `(now-60m .. now-30m]` and `(now-30m .. now]`.

It uses the following functions:

- [last_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) for selecting all the time series, which were existed during the last 30 minutes
- [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier)
- [count](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count) aggregate function
- [and](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) operator

Comment: Thanks, i think that makes sense. Does it matter what *_over_time function is used? Since i'm only interested in metric/label and not it's actual value

Comment: Any other `*_over_time()` function can be used there. This function is needed for selecting all the time series on the time range specified in square brackets (aka lookbehind window). The `last_over_time` function has the lowest overhead in theory, since it just returns the last raw sample per each matching series on the given lookbehind window.